# css selector of even odd when elements are not in same parent

Tags: html, css

In the page, we have 8 images, that could be anywhere in the DOM (very complex logic, irrelevant to the question at hand). What I want is for the even images to have a border of blue, and for the odd images to have a border of red.

I have tried these and non of them is working

```
.timeline-details-image:nth-of-type(even) img
{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.timeline-details-image:nth-of-type(odd) img
{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.timeline-details-image img:nth-of-type(even)
{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.timeline-details-image img:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

What is happening is that since these images don't have a common parent, every image ends up being odd in it's parent container (as it would be first image in the parent container) so they all end up getting red border. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not select the parent elements that *are* siblings? Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Are you suggesting that alternate images inside each parent would require this styling or alternate images inside the `body`?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Alternate images inside the body

Answer (score 0):

Use JS for odd and even image border as below

```
  $(document).ready(function()
   {
    $(".timeline-details-image:even").css("border", "1px solid #cccccc");
    $(".timeline-details-image:odd").css("background", "1ppx solid #ce0000");
}
```

Comment: Better to set an `odd` or `even` class on the items instead of setting inline CSS on them.

Answer (score 0):

CSS alone will not do that for you, you will need some javascript for that. If you are using jQuery, you could do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timeline-details-image').each(function(index) {
        // check if number is even, then apply class 'even' 
        if (index % 2 === 0) $(this).addClass('even');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two new classes timeline-details-image-odd for odd images and timeline-details-image-even for evenimages in your HTML.

And add the below CSS:

```
.timeline-details-image-odd{border: 2px solid red;}

.timeline-details-image-even{border: 2px solid blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @124c41 and the comments above that the requirement is for:

> Alternate images inside the body

the answer would seem to require Javascript

The JQuery would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function(index) {
        // even //
        if (index % 2 === 1) $(this).css("borderBottom", "10px solid red");
        // odd //
        if (index % 2 === 0) $(this).css("borderBottom", "10px solid blue");
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4a29Lz1z/2/)